# How to return multiple results in Postgres but I need to use a variable

Tags: postgresql

I've got an Microsoft SQL background. So what I'm trying to do is something I know I can do in MSSql but I'm dying trying to figure out the equivalent in Postgres (most recent docker version as of the time of this post).

Here's my MSSql.

```
DECLARE @id INTEGER

SELECT @id = Id FROM SomeTable where UniqueName = 'foo' // UniqueName is unique (bet you didn't guess that)

SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Id = @id

SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE Id = @id

SELECT * FROM FinalTable WHERE Id = @id
```

Is this possible?

Initially, I was trying with a CTE (equivalent):

```
WITH vars AS(
    SELECT Id FROM SomeTable where UniqueName = 'foo' 
)

SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Id = vars.Id;

SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE Id = vars.Id;

SELECT * FROM FinalTable WHERE Id = vars.Id;
```

but I then get an error on the 2nd query: `SELECT * FROM AnotherTable` saying that it doesn't know about `vars` anymore.

So, Is it possible to do this in Postgres?

---

EDIT: So I thought this might be possible with PL/pgSQL (extensions for PostgreSQL). I tried this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    @id integer
BEGIN

    SELECT Id INTO id FROM SomeTable WHERE UniqueName = 'foo'

    SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Id = id ;

    SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE Id = id ;

    SELECT * FROM FinalTable WHERE Id = id ;

END $$;
```

but this fails to return any data (yes, I can confirm there is some data for this query) with:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 8 at SQL statement 

SQL state: 42601
```

so I'm really lost, now.

Comment: Maybe a CTE and a single UNION ALL query?

Comment: Nope - because a `UNION ALL` requires all results to have the same columns. I was hoping to return multiple recordsets which have different columns.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with this kind of function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_test(inputName text) RETURNS setof refcursor AS
$$
DECLARE foundid INTEGER;
DECLARE result1 refcursor;
DECLARE result2 refcursor;
DECLARE result3 refcursor;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO foundid FROM SomeTable WHERE UniqueName = inputName;
    result1 = 'First resultset';
    result2 = 'Second resultset';
    result3 = 'Third resultset';
    OPEN result1 FOR SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id = foundid;
    RETURN NEXT result1;
    OPEN result2 FOR SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id = foundid;
    RETURN NEXT result2;
    OPEN result3 FOR SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE id = foundid;
    RETURN NEXT result3;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Retrieving the result is done this way:

- On a SQL client like pgAdmin, execute 1 `FETCH` at a time inside a transaction (if you execute the whole thing at once, pgAdmin will only show the last resultset):

  ```sql
  BEGIN;
  SELECT fun_test('foo');
  FETCH ALL IN "First resultset";
  FETCH ALL IN "Second resultset";
  FETCH ALL IN "Third resultset";
  COMMIT;
  ```
- If your SQL client supports multiple resultset or if you do software development, you may be able to send all queries at once and get several resultsets returned in an approach similar to the below sample I coded with C++/Qt:

  ```cpp
  if (database.open()) {
      QSqlQuery query(database);
      query.exec(
          "SELECT fun_test('foo');" \
          "FETCH ALL IN \"First resultset\";" \
          "FETCH ALL IN \"Second resultset\";" \
          "FETCH ALL IN \"Third resultset\";"
      );
      for (auto rsi = 0; rsi < 3; ++rsi) {
          //By calling nextResult() first, we ignore the first resultset
          //that contains the identifiers of the next resultsets.
          //We may sometimes want to read it though,
          //in which case the for loop must be altered.
          query.nextResult(); 
          if (query.first()) {
              do {
                  //Do something such as:
                  qDebug() << query.record();
              } while (query.next());
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  As you can see, you do not even need a transaction as everything is executed as a single query.
  In a real-world case, you may need 3 separate `do { ... } while(...);` loops, each in charge of its own recordset.
  Sample:

  ```cpp
  query.exec(
      "SELECT fun_test('foo');" \
      "FETCH ALL IN \"First resultset\";" \
      "FETCH ALL IN \"Second resultset\";" \
      "FETCH ALL IN \"Third resultset\";"
  );
  query.nextResult();
  if (query.first()) {
      do {
          //Do something with records from First resultset
      } while (query.next());
  }
  query.nextResult();
  if (query.first()) {
      do {
          //Do something with records from Second resultset
      } while (query.next());
  }
  query.nextResult();
  if (query.first()) {
      do {
          //Do something  with records from Third resultset
      } while (query.next());
  }
  query.finish();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - interested but complicated :( Also, VSCode with the PG extension can return multiple recordsets in a query, unlike pgAdmin4 which does the last statement in a query (which u correctly mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

The `WITH…AS` construct puts the results of the query into a sort of temp table, whose results can be used in a query against another table. It’s all a single statement, though, so you can’t use the result three times like that.

```
WITH vars AS(
    SELECT Id FROM SomeTable where UniqueName = 'foo' 
)
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Id in (select id from vars);
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Comment: If I can't use the result "three times like that" .. then this is not a good solution :(

Comment: The variables you are used to are a feature of T-SQL, not SQL Server. PostgreSQL has it’s own functional programming language, as well as languages based on TCL, Perl and Python. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xplang.html, which might serve your needs.

Comment: "The variables you are used to are a feature of T-SQL, not SQL Server." I think you mean: a feature of T-Sql and not part of SQL (language). I was thinking it was part of SQL .. not a T-SQL "extension" :(

Comment: I guess “...not a part of SQL Server’s SQL dialect” is probably most accurate. I am most familiar with SQL Server, too, so I feel your pain. I like to say, you don’t really understand something until you understand it’s alternatives.

Comment: yep. Here I was hearing good things about postgres and then the one of the first things I tried .. came upon this problem! oof. talk about painful and thinking MSSql is actually pretty damn good.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible using WITH statement, you can fix it by something like that:

```
SELECT set_config('my.vars.id', Id::char, False) FROM SomeTable WHERE UniqueName = 'foo';

SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Id = current_setting('my.vars.id')::int;

SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE Id = current_setting('my.vars.id')::int;

SELECT * FROM FinalTable WHERE Id = current_setting('my.vars.id')::int;
```

Comment: Hi @matt_0806 and thanks for helping me here. Can you please explain what this `set_config` thingy is? is this abusing the configuration settings of pgsql?

Comment: Hi, it should set session-wide configuration variable.
It is in fact quite a setting-hacking solution, but as far as I know the only possible, other than inefficient duplication of with statements in current postgres ecosystem (maybe there are some extension that could chandle it)